# Catch-all messages who not routed in RabbitMQ with header exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have 3 queues in RabbitMQ ( q1, q2, q3 ) that each of them routed by unique header

What is the right way to handle mismatched headers?

There is any "Catch-all" mechanism?

[image: Qs]